# The Adjoint Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a simple question about the adjoint equation for second order linear differential equation. Given an equation of the form

$$P(t)y'' + Q(t)y' + R(t)y = 0$$

Let $u(t)$ be an integrating factor such that the equation

$$M(t)y'' + N(t)y' + S(t)y = 0$$

with $M(t) = u(t)P(t)$, $N(t) = u(t)Q(t)$, $S(t) = u(t)R(t)$ can be written as:

$$(M(t)y')' + (f(t)y)' = 0$$

for a function $f(t)$ that depends on $M(t)$, $N(t)$, and $S(t)$.

Question: Write the solutions of $M(t)y'' + N(t)y' + S(t)y = 0$ in terms of $M(t)$, $f(t)$, and integrals.

So I have:

$$(M(t)y')' = -(f(t)y)'$$

Taking the integral of both sides I get:

$$M(t)y' = -f(t)y$$

Separating the variables I get:

$$\frac{y'}{y} = -\frac{f(t)}{M(t)}$$

My final solution is $y = Ce^{-\frac{f(t)}{M(t)}}$

Is my reasoning correct? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Shouldn't the integration introduce a constant?

Comment: Oh that's right, then would it be M(t)y' = -f(t)y + C? In that case you wouldn't be able to separate the variables right?